How enable ISR on dynamic page routing with next.js 14 app router?
I have an e-commerce website created with Next.js.
I have some routes like:
1. allproducts/page.js
2. allproducts/allproductsbycategories/[...id]/page.js

For the first routing, ISR is enabled, but for the second one with dynamic routing, it seems disabled. (I have added export const revalidate = 300 and the file doesn't have 'use client', but it is still disabled.)
Product categories dynamic route page code is :
// static generation
export const revalidate = 300;

export async function generateMetadata({ params, searchParams }, parent) {
   
    const Products = await getAllProductsByCategories_serverAction(params.id[0])
   
    return {
        title: `RobRob - ${Products[0].categoryName} | blablabla`,
        description: "blablabla",
    }
  }

export default async function Page({params}) {

    const Products = await getAllProductsByCategories_serverAction(params.id[0])

    return (

        <ProductCardsCategory Products={Products} title={Products[0].categoryName}/>

    );
};

How can I enable ISR on dynamic routing? I have searched the documentation for the app router, but it's not clear to me.

I also was wondering If it's not possible because there were not enough documentation about ISR with app router.
Then I found out this migration guides for ISR with dynamic paths.
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/upgrading/app-router-migration#dynamic-paths-getstaticpaths
You could just use 'GenerateStaticParams' with empty array which is counterpart of getStaticPaths.
